# Sum of Functions Converging in Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the following result. If $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $g_n \rightarrow g$ in measure, then $f_n + g_n \rightarrow f + g$ in measure. Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then notice that for any $x \in X$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$(|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon/2) \wedge (|g_n(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon/2) \Longrightarrow |(f_n(x) + g_n(x)) - (f(x) + g(x))| < \epsilon$$

The contrapositive is,
$$|(f_n(x) + g_n(x)) - (f(x) + g(x))| \geq \epsilon \Longrightarrow (|f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon/2) \vee (|g_n(x) - g(x)| \geq \epsilon/2)$$

So,
$$\{ x \in X : |(f_n(x) + g_n(x)) - (f(x) + g(x))| \geq \epsilon \}
\\
\subseteq
\{ x \in X : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon/2 \} \bigcup \{ x \in X : |g_n(x) - g(x)| \geq \epsilon/2\}$$

So by properties of measures,
$$
\mu (\{ x : |(f_n(x) + g_n(x)) - (f(x) + g(x))| \ge \epsilon \})
\\
\leq \mu(\{ x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon/2 \}) + \mu(\{ x : |g_n(x) - g(x)| \geq \epsilon/2 \})
$$
Now, I know that we want the LHS to get arbitrarily small. So suppose $\delta > 0$. By the hypothesis, both of the terms on the RHS will eventually be less than $\delta/2$. So for some $N$, whenever $n > N$,
$$
\mu (\{ x : |(f_n(x) + g_n(x)) - (f(x) + g(x))| \ge \epsilon \}) < \delta/2 + \delta/2 = \delta
$$
Is this proof correct? Is it needlessly long? Does anyone have suggestions for writing these types of proofs? They seem to start out just as their less general counterparts do, except more work needs to be done. Any tips are greatly appreciated as the idea of converging in measure is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and I think the argument you gave is fairly common in measure theory. It is a fine length, the essential point being to observe the “contrapositive” you mentioned.

Similar problems arise quite frequently in probability theory, where convergence in measure is a common mode of convergence. It’s a little tricky to give general tips, but the more you read and the more problems you solve, the better feel you’ll get for this kind of result.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!